# Are sympy matrices really that slow?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I just had a look on sympy and it looks like it's extremely slow.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
from sympy.matrices import zeros
from time import time
import numpy as np

t = time()
M = zeros(500,500)
print("Time", time()-t)

t = time()
M = np.zeros((500,500))
print("Time", time()-t)
```

Sympy takes 1.2s and numpy takes 0.0006s.
There is nothing really going on here. What takes so long?

**Edit:**
What I was really looking for was a library where I can use fast matrix stuff (Gauss eliminiation, multiplication) on fractional values without losing precision. I am now using numpy with `dtype=object` and `Fraction` from python. It's not super fast but better than this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sympy*, as its name shows is a package for *symbolic* mathematics, that is (emphasis mine):

> […] a scientific area that refers to the study and development of algorithms and software for **manipulating mathematical expressions and other mathematical objects**.
>
> [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation)

So, *Sympy* is not optimized for matrix calculation.

As @Michelle pointed out in the comments *SymPy* matrices are symbolic; each entry (even zero) is a *SymPy* object, `sympy.core.numbers.Zero` to be precise.

Also, if you look at the source code, *Sympy* is a pure Python package, whereas *Numpy* has over 50% of its codebase written in C. That probably explains the performance issue you noticed with *Sympy*.

Comment: @Michelle Good point, I didn't want to put too much of the implementation details in my answer but I'll probably add that one if you don't mind :)

Comment: SymPy docs suggest several options to increase performance: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html

Comment: Hi. This answer correctly explains why sympy is slower than numpy; but what I'd really love to know is: what's a good alternative to numpy, that can deal with arrays of fractions?